# SQL merge result set from two select queries and transpose counting

Tags: sql, outer-join

I'm trying to extract data from database with a particular template.

In my database I have the following data:

```
 System | Type | Number
   A      TypeA   1
   A      TypeB   1
   A      TypeA   1
   B      TypeA   1
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
System | #TypeA | #TypeB
   A       2       1
   B       1       0
```

Is it possible with only one query?

I tried to do `full outer join` between two queries without success. I'm curious to know the best solution in terms of performance.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation using a *conditional case expression*

```
select system,
  Sum(case when type='TypeA' then 1 else 0 end) "#TypeA",
  Sum(case when type='Typeb' then 1 else 0 end) "#TypeB"
from t
group by system;
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case I obtaind duplicated row for each type summed: (system=A, typeA= 2, typeb = 0) and then (system=A, typeA=0, typeb=1)

Comment: Sorry I had a group by to delete. Thank you so much!